# File not found when using absolute path

Tags: java, filereader

Each time i give full file path to the FileReader, **FileNotFoundException** is encountered. But just giving the file name after copying the file in the same directory in which program is residing, makes the program execute fine.

```
// Doesn't work

    FileReader in = new FileReader(files_path +"\\"+ "fileName.csv");
    Iterable<CSVRecord> records = CSVFormat.EXCEL.parse(in);
    for (CSVRecord record : records) 
    {
        System.out.println(record.get(7));
    }


//Works 

    FileReader in = new FileReader("fileName.csv");
    Iterable<CSVRecord> records = CSVFormat.EXCEL.parse(in);
    for (CSVRecord record : records) 
    {
        System.out.println(record.get(7));
    }
```

Comment: Use File.separator instead of "\\"

Comment: This is completely unrelated to apache-commons-csv, don't you think? A wild guess: files_path is wrong?

Comment: @FlorianAlbrecht Yup..completely agree with u.. but i am not able to find what's wrong when i give the absolute path of the file.. so i thought there might be some issue with apache-commons-csv.

Answer (score 0):

The file denoted by

```
files_path +"\\"+ "fileName.csv"
```

does not exist. This is why you encounter this error.

Potential causes:

- `files_path` represents an invalid or non-existing path
- `files_path` itself ends with a backslash (although that should not cause that many problems on Windows)
- You are not on Windows, in which case you'd need to use a forward slash as file separator. As already suggested in a comment, use the Java constant `File.separator` to be platform independent.

Comment: Sorry.. forgot to mention the value of file_path.. file_path="D://Currentpro//NewFolder"

Comment: @Kspace Do you really mean, with two **forward** slashes?

Comment: No.. Just one.. sorry

Comment: @Kspace Add this information to your question. Also, you should store the whole path into a String variable and print it to `System.out` before invoking the `FileReader` constructor. Then, you can easily verify if this is a valid path. As you are on Windows, try replacing forward slashes in the path with `File.separator`.